# How do you know which dependencies to install for Adobe products in Wine?

Tags: wine, adobe

I was looking through the questions here and people seem to know what dependencies are required by Adobe CS6 products like PhotoShop or Illustrator.
I can not find on Internet any source that specify which dependencies are required by program...

Is there any automatic detector? 
I am looking for dependencies for Adobe Illustrator CS6 so it works the best.

Comment: You could try using PlayOnLinux, which is kind of a frontend to manage wine applications. It contains an installer script for Photoshop CS6. Note that it does not really integrate with your existing normal Wine installation IIRC but might download and install whatever Wine version and packages it finds appropriate for each application you install through it.

Comment: Winehq.com offers a lot of information, see e. g. [this](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26011) for Adobe Illustrator CS6. Using playonlinux as suggested is a very good idea to keep your apps in separated environments by the way.

Comment: That link says only msxml3 is required for illustrator but on other topic I found 10 other dependencies that are also required... otherwise installer won't even initialize that is why i asked.

Comment: @Luka Well, I would just give it a try, if it fails just search the web for the error messages you get – that's how I do it.

Comment: I did install cc 2015 and cs6 package many times but I am just asking for other experiences so I can avoid any bugs.